# Is there an anthology of classic papers on electricity?

Tags: physics, electromagnetism, resource-recommendation

I'm trying to find a book similiar to Stephen Brush "Kinetic Theory of Gases: An Anthology of Classic Papers With Historical Commentary".
The electricity version, let's say!
I like to see how subjects and theories developed and nothing is more interesting to read classic papers on the subjects.
If you do know anything, please share!

Answer (score 1):

If French works for you, O. Darrigol's [*Les équations de Maxwell: de MacCullagh à Lorentz* (2005)](https://www.amazon.fr/dp/2701130751) is such an anthology, with comments drawn from his earlier [book](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0954.78001). Such collections are likely a dying breed, as all papers (in this case, nine by MacCullagh, Maxwell, Lorenz, Heaviside, Hertz, Lorentz) become freely available online.

Answer (score 1):

See the hefty § "Magnetism and Electricity", pp. 387-616 of [*A Source Book in Physics*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=5699) by William Francis Magie. It contains selections, prefaced with a biography, of 37 scientists including Gilbert, Franklin, Coulomb, Galvani, Volta, Ørsted, Biot and Savart, Arago, Ampère, Ohm, Faraday, Lenz, Gauss, Joule, Maxwell, Hall, Hertz, et al.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't contain the actual papers, unfortunately, but perhaps you would still find it useful: [*A History of the Theories of Aether and Electricity*](https://archive.org/details/historyoftheorie00whitrich). It's fairly detailed and is a second-best alternative if you can't find an anthology of classic papers.